# Older short science fiction story about a flying craft, gaining its lift from by hundreds of vertical screws

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short story about a flying craft, gaining its lift from by hundreds of vertical (Archimedes?) screws. It may have been set in London.

Obviously this is a very old story, possible H.G. Wells or Jules Verne.

Unfortunately, this is all that I can recall, other than it was read in the mid 1970's but is obviously much older.

---

I've checked and it's not "*Robur the Conqueror*".

Comment: http://www.online-literature.com/verne/robur-the-conqueror/7/?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: You've said you can't remember anything else about it, but I'm guessing that's not true. For example, what language did you read the story in? Why was it 'obviously' much older? How short a story was it (a single page, several pages, novella sized)? Aside from flying in the ship, do you recall any other events? Was the story set on Earth or another planet? Did the story have a protagonist (and if so, who was he or she, what was their name, did they have a job title)?

Comment: You've repeatedly stated that it's obviously older. What made you think that?

Comment: I assumed that most people know that the older a story is the cruder the application of force to solve a problem.
This is due to the lack of technology available to society.

The further back a story was written the cruder the application of force used to solve a problem.

Examples are:-
The use of a giant gun to shoot a capsule to the moon.
"From the Earth to the Moon: A Direct Route in 97 Hours, 20 Minutes" by Jules Verne in 1865.

Also:
The use of a Hot Air ballon to journey to the Moon.
"The Unparalleled Adventure of One Hans Pfaall" by Edgar Allan Poe in 1835.

Comment: Even further back we have:
The use of a flock of geese tied to a chariot to get the protagonist to the moon.
"The Man on the Moone" by Francis Godwin in 1638.
This last has been attributed by some to be the first science fiction story.
I disagree with this an attribute that honor to the works of Homer.

As you can see from these examples the pattern is clear,
the writer innovates on then 'Current' technology in their stories.

Comment: From this we can deduce that the story I seek, that uses application of power to screwws to propel a craft, 
must lie somewhere between the invention the steam engine and the invention of the helicopter.
The author may have been influenced by "aerial screw" drawing by Leonardo da Vinci in 1487/1490.

Extra Notes:
The story was in English, the location was Earth (the usual exploration of the Earth story?),
the story was short definitely not a Novella.

Comment: There are entire genres based on dated references to technology; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk. Was the film *Wild Wild West* **written** in 1870 because everything's based on clockwork and steam?

Comment: The more one tries to force old memories the more likely that cross-linking occurs.

This could result in:
 The concatenation of two or more plots.
 The confabulation of new data

I was attempting to avoid confusion and not mislead the extremely helpful contributors on StackExchange.

Comment: Yes, of course I stand corrected. I had for some reason completely forgotten the existance of steampunk. This story was read before that subgenre had a name! (1987). I am investigating to see if it does fall into that category. Many thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe Jules Verne's "Robur the Conqueror".  He was a bit like Captain Nemo only with an airship instead of a submarine.

Comment: Additional details on Robur -- the ship's hull was hypercompressed paper (foreshadowing modern composites), the lifting screws were powered by electric motors (from batteries in the keel), and Robur had set up a factory to build his batteries, motors, screws,and the paper hull material in a crater in North Carolina -- which factory he destroyed when the ship left the crater for the last time.